# How do I set the format of toString methods with ToStringBuilder in commons-lang?

Tags: java, tostring, apache-commons-lang

how do I configure the setting of the format for toString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToStringBuilder.setDefaultStyle(ToStringStyle style)`

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringStyle.html